# MYSQL: Updating a customer field based on a partial match to another table's field

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

customer, company

The customer table contains company_id and email_address while the company table contains company_id and URL

I'd like to run a query to update all the customer table's company_id to the matching company_id based on a partial match -- specifically if the customer's email_address contains the URL.

For example, if customer has customer@google.com it checks the company table to see if that email contains the URL google.com, and if so, it gives the customer the matching company_id from the company table.

What's an efficient way to do this in single query? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would do exactly what you want:

```
UPDATE customer 
LEFT JOIN company 
    ON (customer.email LIKE CONCAT('%@', company.URL, '%'))
SET customer.company_id = company.company_id
WHERE company.company_id IS NOT NULL;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/89765/1

Comment: Can I remove the trailing % in the CONCAT, to differentiate uniqueness between, say, website.co and website.co.uk?

Comment: You can and probably should, was taking the comment "checks the company table to see if that email contains the URL" to literally